# How can I add another option to this custom post function?

Tags: custom-post-types, rating

I'm currently developing a games database for my wordpress site and one of the custom functions is entering a review score for a game, we have a 1-10 based rating system but I wish to add another option to this loop "No Review", how can I do this?

```
<select style="width: 100px" name="games_database_rating">
  <?php // Generate all items of drop-down list
  for ( $rating = 10; $rating >= 1; $rating -- ) {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $rating; ?>" <?php echo selected( $rating, $game_rating ); ?>>
  <?php echo $rating; ?>/10 <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a static `<option>` element before you start your loop.

```
<select style="width: 100px" name="games_database_rating">
  <option value="none">No Rating</option>
  <?php // Generate all items of drop-down list
      for ( $rating = 10; $rating >= 1; $rating -- ) {
  ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $rating; ?>" <?php echo selected( $rating, $game_rating ); ?>>
     <?php echo $rating; ?>/10 <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Now your `select` will start out with "No Rating", and you can still choose a number. When you submit the form, just check for "none" or the number.

Comment: Ahh but if No Review is selected then the database wont remember the selection in the dashboard because it's outside of the loop?

Comment: Actually ignore that, it seems to be working perfectly :)